# Setting email nickname for aliased domain in Google Apps

Tags: email, g-suite, alias

I have set up my main domain for Google Apps (`intecro.com`) and I've set alias domain in Google Apps for (`intecro.cz`).

I have administrator account `admin@intecro.com` and it automaticaly gave me *nickname* `admin@intecro.cz`, which is great, but I am unable to add other nickname `@intecro.cz`. It automaticaly suffixes every nickname with `@intecro.com`.

Is it even possible to set email *nickname* for an aliased domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any nickname set up under the primary domain (intecro.com) will also be available under the domain alias. This means if you have the nickname admin.nickname@interco.com, any mail sent to admin.nickname@interco.cz will be delivered to the account as well.

It is noted at the bottom of this help page.
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327